# Scaling iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone

I'm running Xcode 6 on my MBAir, and when I run the simulator it's larger than my screen vertically. Makes it difficult to test!

I looked under Hardware but all the other options are even larger. Is there a way to do half-scale or something similar so I don't have to scroll so much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Your device then hold command button then press 1 or 2 or 3 and select scale as per your requirement.